# Is it possible for Tampermonkey to share one storage on different websites?

Tags: cross-domain, tampermonkey

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102968/tampermonkey-how-to-use-it-on-two-different-websites), but has more details.

- "share"ing is expected to be done by one script.
- "storage" is which `GM_{g,s}etValue` use.
- "different websites" are those which have different origins.

My scheme now:

- On website A, I insert an iframe of site B, and synchronize storage by `postMessage`.

Information I've got:

- From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025235/get-2-userscripts-to-interact-with-each-other), it seems that Tampermonkey used to support share data cross-originly.

Comment: Simply add `@match` for both URLs (the page and the iframe) so the storage will be automatically the same, [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6053388).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by wOxxOm, in order for 2 domains to share data via GM storage API, the script must run on both e.g. via `@match`.

<s>However, in Tampermonkey the domains will get access to the data at the time script was injected.</s>

**Update:** As pointed out by wOxxOm, "*Both Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey provide real-time access to the real values. They do it by propagating the change to all tabs/frames where this script instance runs.*"

You can also use `GM_addValueChangeListener()` to listen to changes to the storage.

> [GM_addValueChangeListener()](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_addValueChangeListener)
> Adds a change listener to the storage and returns the listener ID.
> 'name' is the name of the observed variable.
> The 'remote' argument of the callback function shows whether this value was modified from the instance of another tab (true) or within this script instance (false).
> Therefore this functionality can be used by scripts of different browser tabs to communicate with each other.

Note: In Greasemonkey & FireMonkey, the asynchronous `GM.getValue()` would always get the current up-to-date data.

Comment: Both Tampermonkey/Violentmonkey provide real-time access to the real values. They do it by propagating the change to all tabs/frames where this script instance runs.